# Drupal Ajax Forms

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-forms, drupal-ajax

I have a form in Drupal that calls an external database in Netezza. Retrieve this data from Netezza lasts about 10 seconds. Then, based on that information I have to build a select control to let the user choose from a list of categories. When the user chooses a category I do another expensive call to Netezza to retrieve more information.

The problem is that for the second interaction (when the user chose a category) the form is reprocessed and therefore doing 2 expensive calls to Netezza, not one as anyone would expect or desire.

Do you know a workaround for this situation? Is there a way to do an ajax call using the Drupal Ajax Framework without rebuilding the entire form?

Thanks.

PD: Reading documentation about the Ajax Framework I guess a solution could be using another path specifiying #ajax['path'], but haven´t fully tested that behavior and will be thankful if you share your experience.

PD2: I would prefer a workaround based on the Drupal Ajax Framework, not in a caching mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend you to have a look into [Drupal Examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples), specially the module called ajax_example.

this is a fast sample code, might not be running, but just to give you the idea

```
function expensive_form($form, &$form_state) {

  $form['category'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Cateogry'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => first_expensive_operation(),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'choose_category_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'ajax-div',
      // 'method' defaults to replaceWith, but valid values also include
      // append, prepend, before and after.
      // 'method' => 'replaceWith',
      // 'effect' defaults to none. Other valid values are 'fade' and 'slide'.
      'effect' => 'slide',
      // 'speed' defaults to 'slow'. You can also use 'fast'
      // or a number of milliseconds for the animation to last.
      // 'speed' => 'slow',
    ),
  );

  $form['ajax_fieldset'] = array(
    '#title' => t("Ajax Fields"),
    // The prefix/suffix provide the div that we're replacing, named by
    // #ajax['wrapper'] above.
    '#prefix' => '<div id="ajax-div">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#description' => t('This is where we get automatically updated something'),
  );

  // this will only be executed on the second run of the form
  // when the category is set.
  if (isset($form_state['values']['category'])) {
    $form['ajax_fieldset']['something'] = array(
      '#title' => t('Somethings'),
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#options' => second_expensive_operation($form_state['values']['category']),
    );
  }

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );

  return $form;
}



/**
 * Callback element needs only select the portion of the form to be updated.
 * Since #ajax['callback'] return can be HTML or a renderable 
 * array, we can just return a piece of the form.
 */
function choose_category_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['ajax_fieldset'];
}
```